# I want to insert and update date in java using jdatechooser in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have make a product form in which i have to add products manufacture and expiry date in mysql database table.When the save button press it insert the data in mysql database but when i try to update it show me error

```
   if(cb1.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Any Type"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Select User type");
        }
       
            
        try
        {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retailer","root","");
            java.util.Date date=new java.util.Date();
            int n=cb1.getSelectedIndex();
              String sql="Insert into stockable(CategoryID, ProductName, Quantity, SaleUnitPrice, CurrentPurchasePrice, ExpiryDate, MfturDate, StockThesoldQty, Description) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
            PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
             pst.setString(1,String.valueOf(n));
            pst.setString(2, productname.getText());
              pst.setString(3, quantity.getText());
                 pst.setString(4, saleprice.getText());
                 pst.setString(5, purchaseprice.getText());
                 pst.setString(6, (expirydate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()));
                 pst.setString(7, (mandate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()));
                pst.setString(8, thesoldqty.getText());
                pst.setString(9,desc.getText());
              
                
                int rs= pst.executeUpdate();
            if(rs>0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"data inserted");
                productname.setText("");
                saleprice.setText("");
                purchaseprice.setText("");
                  thesoldqty.setText("");
                  String sql2="Select * from stockable";
            Statement st1=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2=st1.executeQuery(sql2);
          
            while(rs2.next())
            {
                String id=String.valueOf(rs2.getInt("Productid"));
                String catid=String.valueOf(rs2.getInt("categoryid"));
                String usertypename=rs2.getString("ProductName");
                String qty=String.valueOf(rs2.getInt("Quantity"));
                String saleprice=String.valueOf(rs2.getInt("SaleUnitPrice"));
                String purprice=String.valueOf(rs2.getInt("CurrentPurchasePrice"));
                String expirydate=String.valueOf(rs2.getDate("ExpiryDate"));
                String manudate=String.valueOf(rs2.getDate("MfturDate"));
                String StockThesoldQty=String.valueOf(rs2.getInt("StockThesoldQty"));
                String description=rs2.getString("description");
                String tbdata[]={id,catid,usertypename,qty,saleprice,purprice,expirydate,manudate,StockThesoldQty,description};
                DefaultTableModel tblmodel=(DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
                tblmodel.addRow(tbdata);
            }
                  
               
            }
               
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
```

Now the inserting is done now when i fetch the row from table

```
   int i=jTable2.getSelectedRow();
        TableModel model=jTable2.getModel();
        n.setText(model.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
        n.setVisible(false);
        productname.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
       quantity.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
       saleprice.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
       purchaseprice.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 5).toString());
       thesoldqty.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 8).toString());
      desc.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 9).toString());
      String name=model.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
      cb1.setSelectedItem(name);
         try {
                 java.util.Date date= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse((String)model.getValueAt(i,6));
                  java.util.Date date2= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse((String)model.getValueAt(i,7));
             expirydate.setDate(date);
             mandate.setDate(date2);
         } catch (ParseException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(product.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
```

and now when i update the date of the form

```
   try{
            
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retailer","root","");
            
             String query = "UPDATE stockable SET ProductName='"+productname.getText()+"',Quantity='"+quantity.getText()+"',SaleUnitPrice='"+saleprice.getText()+"',CurrentPurchasePrice='"+purchaseprice.getText()+"',ExpiryDate='"+expirydate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()+"',MfturDate='"+mandate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()+"',StockThesoldQty='"+thesoldqty.getText()+"',Description='"+desc.getText()+"' WHERE Productid ='"+n.getText()+"'";
                    Statement ps = conn.createStatement();
                   ps.execute(query);
                   
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Update");
             
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        }
```

it show error that data truncation incorrect date format
ERROR SHOWING:"data truncation incorrect date value"Wed Sep 08 00:00:00 PKT 2021 for column 'retailer' 'stockable''expirydate' at row 1"

Comment: Print the exception.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you don't show us the complete error message, we can't help you. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Please show the attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: data truncation incorrect date value"Wed Sep 08 00:00:00 PKT 2021 for column 'retailer' 'stockable''expirydate' at row 1

Comment: data truncation incorrect date value"Wed Sep 08 00:00:00 PKT 2021 for column 'retailer' 'stockable''expirydate' at row 1 showing this error

Answer (score 0):

[getUiComponent](http://javadox.com/com.toedter/jcalendar/1.4/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/IDateEditor.html#getUiComponent()) does not return the date itself rather the UI component which contains the date.

Try to replace

```
           pst.setString(6, (expirydate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()));
           pst.setString(7, (mandate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()));
```

with:

```
           pst.setString(6, (((JTextField)expiryDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()));
           pst.setString(7, (((JTextField)mandate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()));
```

Comment: insertion is done but when i click on table to put back the data row for updation there it give error.data truncation incorrect date value "data truncation incorrect date value"Wed Sep 08 00:00:00 PKT 2021 for column 'retailer' 'stockable''expirydate' at row 1